# have header and footer that are on out side of iframe appear and disapear when mouse enters general area

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, header

I have an iframe inside a main page container. I have managed to remove the second scroll bar that is in the main html. Leaving only the iframe scroll, this was done by request of a higher up. We have mandatory headers and footers that need to appear at all times. We decided to get creative and added some .js to out html that makes the headers and footers appear and disappear. The only problem is this causes the iframe to not take up the whole page height. because if the headers and footers are shown when mouse is over them and the iframe is too long then the footers get hidden under the page. (cant scroll down to them because the scrollbar was removed.) 
What I am trying to get at is there a way I can have both work? Ill post the code.

```
*JavaScript*
function show_topnav()
{
document.getElementById('nybe-top-nav').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('nygov-universal-navigation-frame').style.display="block";
}

function hide_topnav()
{
document.getElementById('nybe-top-nav').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('nygov-universal-navigation-frame').style.display="none";
}


function show_bottomnav()
{
document.getElementById('nybe-footer').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('nygov-universal-footer-frame').style.display="block";
}

function hide_bottomnav()
{
document.getElementById('nybe-footer').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('nygov-universal-footer-frame').style.display="none";
}
```

here is the html

```
 <header id="test-header"  onMouseLeave="hide_topnav()">    

   <iframe id="nygov-universal-navigation-frame"  title="NY Gov Universal       Navigation" class="nygov-universal-container" width="100%" height="86px" src="//static-assets.ny.gov/load_global_menu/ajax?iframe=true" data-updated="2014-11-07 08:30" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:86px;" scrolling="no">
            Your browser does not support iFrames
</iframe>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <noscript>
    <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-T4FP6H" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"  title="Google tag manager" ></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];var j=d.createElement(s);var dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;j.type='text/javascript';j.async=true;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-T4FP6H');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<div id="nybe-wrapper"> 

<!-- Begin the top navigation -->

    <div id="nybe-top-nav">
        <div id="nybe-account">
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Your Account</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nys-global-header horizontal unstacked">
            <h1><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>New York Business Express</a></h1>
            <ul id="nys-global-nav">
              <li>
                <a href="#" title="DEVELOPMENT">Start your Business</a>
              </li>
              <li>

              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hidden-top" onMouseEnter="show_topnav()"> </div><!-- helper div for onMouseEnter -->

</header><!-- end header -->
```

here is some of the css

```
    html{
 overflow-y: hidden; 
}

body.nybe-opa-frame #main-content{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body.nybe-opa-frame #main-content > iframe{
    min-height:650px !important;
    width:100%;
    border:none;
}
body.nybe-opa-frame #nybe-footer {
    margin-top:-5px;
}
/* end opa frame*/



/*#hidden-top{background-color: #142047;}*/


/*added two help divs  to use on mouse enter events for the page 
opacity is set to 0 so they cant be seen */
#hidden-bottom,#hidden-top{
opacity: 0.0;
height: 20px;

}

/*set all the headers and footers to display none*/
#nygov-universal-navigation-frame,#nybe-top-nav,#nybe-footer,#nygov-universal-footer-frame{
 display: none;
}
```

most of the code was not made me my higherup created most of the page the iframe comes from an external source. 
Any Ideas would be great! I know this is kind of a weird post. What i Have now works pretty well but I feel like there is a better more efficient way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: So in a nut shell what the heck are you asking?

Comment: yea sorry it was long and i wasnt sure how to phrase it. I have an Iframe inside a div. on the outside is other html junk. the headers and footers are stuck at the top and bottom of the page. i want to know if there if there is a better way to have the header/footer appear and disappear better than what I have. while not affecting the outer html size wise. The Iframe has a fixed height because i want to accommodate the header and footer correctly

Comment: Do you want the iframe to fill the page and push the header up and the footer down?

Comment: I think I just realized what I have to do. All I want now is to just let page scroll down to see the footer. If the page is shrunk down. But i dont want the scroll bar to show. (only the iframes)